# Laravel DB limit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to take data from DB using 'limit' how to do that in laravel? Eloquent

```
->limit($value)
```

takes only one value but I need to get a range. I mean for example in a request I send **starting point** and **range**:

```
0 and 10 (i want to start getting records from first and get next 10)
```

and then

```
10 and 10 (i want to start getting records from 10th and get next 10)
```

In MySQL query its possible to make `LIMIT 0, 10 / LIMIT 10, 10`
What's the way to do that from laravel? `->limit(0,10)`?

Answer (score 7):

You can do like this,

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->offset(10)
                ->limit(5)
                ->get();
```

Please go through [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) here for more details and documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You should try this

```
//For first 0 to 10 record

$users = User::take(10)->get();

// For 11 to 20 record

$users = User::skip(10)->take(10)->get();

// Or if it is for pagination then you should use

$users = User::paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use skip and take,
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$page` into the request and use below to get the result.

```
->limit(0 * $page,10)
```

Page must be start with 0.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `->limit(0, $page*10)`? Because any number multiplied by zero is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$users = User::skip(0)->take(10)->get();
```